# How to move one server doc file to another s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server

How can we move or copy one server doc file  to another server s3 bucket. I have details of both of the server. Can we move or copy it using code like in PHP ?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy one server doc file to another server s3 bucket"? Are you wanting to upload a file from a computer to Amazon S3, or are you wanting to copy an object between two Amazon S3 buckets? Please edit your question to clarify what you are wanting to do and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are asking how to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket.

The simplest way is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://mybucket/foo.txt
```

If you wish to use this via PHP, then you can use the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/?id=docs_gateway). It has a [`PutObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) command that adds an object to an Amazon S3 bucket.